# Calculating percentages based on a known ratio but unknown values

Tags: percentages

I am mixing a chemical solution and working up a chart for this.

The ratio is:

49% part 1
49% part 2
2% part 3

Part 1 and part 2 are always the same quantity.

If I start from a *known total quantity* — ie, “I want to make a total of 1000mL of solution” — this is easy to calculate:

Total *x* mL = (*x* mL * .49) + (*x* mL * .49) + (*x* mL *.02)

My question is this: is there a way to calculate the amounts “backwards”.

Example: “I have 5mL of part three. How many mL of part 1 and part 2 do I need?”

Or: “I have 8 mL of parts 1 and parts 2. How many mL of part 3 do I need?”

(Edited to clarify question)

Comment: Hi, welcome to MathSE! I think your question is a bit unclear. First, do you want to say that you are certain that parts 1 and 2 have the same amount of weight? Or are you saying that part 1 can have some amount $z_1$ and part 2 can have a different amount $z_2$?

Comment: Yes, if I understood you correctly. If everything is in mL. If you have 5 of part 3, then the total will be $5/0.02 = 250$, and from that you can calculate the other parts.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the second half. I hope that makes it clears!

Comment: @CoveredInChocolate I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @CoveredInChocolate Right! So simple I'm embarrassed. If you post as an answer I can accept it!

Comment: @EthanBolker: All right, I added an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if I understood you correctly. If everything is in mL. If you have 5 of part 3, then the total will be $5/0.02=250$, and from that you can calculate the other parts.